# I want to replace words from a file by the line no using python i have a list of line no?

Tags: python, list, file

if I have a file like:

```
Flower
Magnet
5001
100
0
```

and I have a list containing line number, which I have to change.

`list =[2,3]`

How can I do this using python and the output I expect is:

```
Flower
Most
Most
100
0
```

Code that I've tried:

```
f = open("your_file.txt","r")
line = f.readlines()[2]
print(line)
if line=="5001":
    print "yes"
else:
    print "no"
```

but it is not able to match.
i want to overwrite the file which i am reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may simply loop through the list of indices that you have to replace in your file (my original answer needlessly looped through all lines in the file):

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
  data = f.read().splitlines()
  replace = {1,2}
  for i in replace:
    data[i] = 'Most'
  print('\n'.join(data))
```

Output:

```
Flower
Most
Most
100
0
```

To overwrite the file you have opened with the replacements, you may use the following:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r+') as f:
  data = f.read().splitlines()
  replace = {1,2}
  for i in replace:
    data[i] = 'Most'
  f.seek(0)
  f.write('\n'.join(data))
  f.truncate()
```

Comment: i want to write in that file too

Comment: Append or overwrite?

Comment: overwrite  the file

Comment: @RinkiNag updated to show how to overwrite the file.

Comment: hey chrisz can you help me how to overwrite in that file

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you're having this problem is that when you take a line from a file opened in python, you also get the newline character (`\n`) at the end. To solve this, you could use the [string.strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) function, which will automatically remove these characters.

Eg.

```
f = open("your_file.txt","r")
line = f.readlines()

lineToCheck = line[2].strip()

if(lineToCheck == "5001"):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Comment: can u help to overwrite in that file too

Comment: I'd have a look at a tutorial (something like [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm) from Opening and Closing Files onwards)